# How to loop through the links of the page and write all the http links in a file in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to load a url and check all the http and https links of the page and put these links into two different files.I am using javascript and when I try to write the all the http urls in the file only the last one is written while the others are not written.Below is the code

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var request = require('request');
var fs = require("fs");

jsdom.env(
  'http://www.google.com', ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function(error, window) {
    console.log("There are", window.$('.body').find('img').length, "img");
    var $ = window.$;
    $($('.body').find('a')).each(function() {
      var src = $(this).attr('href');
      if (src.startsWith('http://')) {
        console.log(src)
        fs.writeFile('out.html', src,
          function(err) {
            if (err) throw error;
          })
      }
    })
  });
```

How to make this code wrote all the http link to the out.html file.Right now it just writes the last link.

Comment: THis seems Like 2 questions in one, 2 basic questions in one might i add. Besides that, Are you sure you are not overwriting the last one you wrote each time you add a new one?

Comment: Looping is  done and i can see the results in console but while it is writing in the file only the last one is getting written

Comment: So you are not sure. I agree with Mike on this one, You probably didnt read all the documentation and missed the part about what writeFile intricately does.

Answer (score 3):

> when I try to write the all the http urls in the file only the last one is written while the others are not written

That's because you're using [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) which either creates a new file or overwrites an existing file with what you passed to it.

What you want to do is append to the file, which you can do with [`fs.appendFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback):

```
fs.appendFile('out.html', src, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```